# Mobile Zonal OCR document scanner in offline

Tags: android, ios, image-processing, ocr

I am looking for a mobile sdk which can be capture and process a document using zonal OCR, would return a value which is part of a predefined area in an document in offline.

I have gone through some of the commercial sdk like Abbyy, ScanBot. But was not fulfilling my requirement. I would like to know if there are other sdk which i have missed ?? . Thanks for the suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I work for the company that created the LEADTOOLS SDK. If you haven't tried it, there's a [free evaluation edition here.](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main)

The evaluation comes with free technical support through email and chat.

The OCR works either by automatically creating zones, or by accepting pre-defined zones you specify. There are native libraries for different platforms, but if you want to use the same source code on both Android and iOS, you can use our Xamarin SDK (part of the main Evaluation for Windows).

The following code shows how you can define a zone and recognize text using LEADTOOLS classes:

```
using (IOcrPage ocrPage = ocrEngine.CreatePage(rasterImage, OcrImageSharingMode.AutoDispose))
{
  LogicalRectangle bounds = LogicalRectangle.FromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom, LogicalUnit.Pixel);
  OcrZone zone = new OcrZone();
  zone.ZoneType = OcrZoneType.Text;
  zone.Bounds = bounds;
  ocrPage.Zones.Add(zone);
  ocrPage.Recognize(null);
  string text = ocrPage.GetText(-1);
}
```